# Composite-likelihood ratio test

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, likelihood-ratio, quasi-likelihood

I am interested in a number of articles (such as [Kim and Stephan 2002](http://www.genetics.org/content/160/2/765.short) and follow-up articles) that use composite likelihood ratio tests to infer selection pressure on linked (phased) genetic data. I have never encountered composite likelihood functions before and I would love a simple example of what it is and what is its purpose.

**Can you give me a very simple example of the use of a composite-likelihood ratio test?**

---

From the little easy information I could find for the moment, I feel like receiving contradictory information.

> A quasi-maximum likelihood estimate (QMLE, also known as a "pseudo-likelihood estimate" or a "composite likelihood estimate") is an estimate of a parameter θ in a statistical model that is formed by maximizing a function that is related to the logarithm of the likelihood function, but is not equal to it. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-maximum_likelihood)

I suppose that a quasi-Poisson GLM uses a quasi likelihood function allowing for taking into account a variance that differs from the mean due to non-independence of the data values.

> A composite likelihood consists of a combination of valid likelihood objects, usually related to small subsets of data. The merit of composite likelihood is to reduce the computational complexity so that it is possible to deal with large datasets and very complex models, even when the use of standard likelihood or Bayesian methods is not feasible. [Varin and Vidoni 2004 - quote from the abstract](http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/content/92/3/519.short)

I fail to see the relationship between this definition and the above wikipedia definition. In the wikipedia definition, it sounds like a composite likelihood function is just a function somehow related to a likelihood function that one could typically use to deal with non-independence of data values. In the Varing and Vidoni's definition, it sounds like a composite likelihood function is a combination of marginal likelihood functions and we use it in order to save computational effort for multidimensional data.